# Как впихнуть java -jar OptiFine 1.18.2.jar в исп. файл Python?

Tags: python, java, minecraft

Здрасте, как мне впихнуть чтобы при нажатии на клавишу 1 была исполнена команда java -jar OptiFine 1.18.2.jar? Но чтобы не при запуске консоли?

Код которые я скляпнул за 1ч:

```
from colorama import init, Fore #/
from colorama import Back       #|
from colorama import Style      #|
import msvcrt                   #|
#-----------Библы-----------------

print("")
print(Fore.WHITE + "      ███████╗██╗░░░░░░█████╗░██╗░░░██╗███╗░░██╗░█████╗░██╗░░██╗███████╗██████╗░")
print(Fore.WHITE + "      ██╔════╝██║░░░░░██╔══██╗██║░░░██║████╗░██║██╔══██╗██║░░██║██╔════╝██╔══██╗")
print(Fore.BLUE + "      █████╗░░██║░░░░░███████║██║░░░██║██╔██╗██║██║░░╚═╝███████║█████╗░░██████╔╝")
print(Fore.BLUE + "      ██╔══╝░░██║░░░░░██╔══██║██║░░░██║██║╚████║██║░░██╗██╔══██║██╔══╝░░██╔══██╗")
print(Fore.RED + "      ███████╗███████╗██║░░██║╚██████╔╝██║░╚███║╚█████╔╝██║░░██║███████╗██║░░██║")
print(Fore.RED + "      ╚══════╝╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚═╝░╚═════╝░╚═╝░░╚══╝░╚════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚═╝")
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
print("                От создателей EscapeWorld〡Выбран сервер: SCreate")
print(" ")
print("Выберите:")
print("1: Старт игры")
print("2: Выбор версии")
print("3: Настройка лаунчера")

def get_char():
    return msvcrt.getch().decode('utf-8')

option = ""

while True:
    key = get_char()
    if key == "1":
        option = "Начинаем играть!"
        print("Проверяю...")
        print("Загружаем...")
        #Вот сюда надо впихнуть как то java -jar OptiFine 1.18.2.jar
        break
    elif key == "2":
        option = "Выбор версии"
        print("В разработке.")
    elif key == "3":
        option = "Настройка лаунчера"
        print("В разработке.")
    elif key == "q":
        break
print(option)
```

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону subprocess

Comment: subprocess? Извини, не пойму, я в питоне в первый день

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте я вам приведу два примера с subprocess:

1. Запуск с параметрами.

```
import subprocess
import os

current_directory = 'C:\\Users\\Amgarak\\Desktop'
executable_path = os.path.join(current_directory, 'clickermann.exe')
script_argument = 'дополнительный параметр запуска'

# Выполнение исполняемого файла
subprocess.run([executable_path, script_argument], shell=True)
```

2. Без параметров.

```
import subprocess
import os

current_directory = 'C:\\Users\\Amgarak\\Desktop'
my_path = os.path.join(current_directory, 'install.bat')

# Выполнение бат-файла
subprocess.run([my_path], shell=True)
```

Comment: Благодарю! Теперь буду знать)